# In the window environment, start notify and write_gatt_char through bleak do not work

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth-lowenergy

```
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakClient
def notify_callback(sender: int, data: bytearray):
    print('sender: ', sender, 'data: ', data)

async def connect(address):
    async with BleakClient(address, timeout=5.0) as client:     
        print('connected')
        services = await client.get_services()
        for service in services:
            print('service uuid:', service.uuid)
            for characteristic in service.characteristics:
                print('  uuid:', characteristic.uuid)
                print('  handle:', characteristic.handle) 
                print('  properties: ', characteristic.properties)
                if 'notify' in characteristic.properties:                     
                    print('try to activate notify.')
                    await client.start_notify(characteristic, notify_callback)
        if client.is_connected:
            d = "5303e803ff45"
            data_to_write = bytearray.fromhex(d)
            await client.write_gatt_char(characteristic.uuid,data_to_write,response=True)
        

    print('disconnect')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(connect(address2))
```

window10
python : 3.12.0
bleak : 0.21.1

File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\bleak\backends\winrt\client.py", line 974, in start_notify
await winrt_char.write_client_characteristic_configuration_descriptor_async(
OSError: [WinError -2147023673] User canceled the action. -> The error keeps appearing. I confirmed that it was paired with a Windows Bluetooth device. We also confirmed data transmission and reception via Nordic. Errors occur only in bleak.

I don't know what else I need to do in a Windows environment.
I heard that UWP is good, so I experimented with it and got similar errors. From what I remember, they were unreachable and oserror.

I want to keep it bleak. Please let me know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you try to use a coroutine as a callback ? I.e. async def notify_callback

Comment: @LucasMeier I haven't tried async def notify_callback. But I ran it on my laptop, it worked. It doesn't work on desktop. I'm not sure what the difference is...

Comment: I just had a WinError this morning, because I did not enable bluetooth on my laptop. Maybe you are having an issue with your bluetooth stack ? not in the code